# Error installing 'AICcmodavg' and 'unmarked': ‘palette.colors’ is not exported by 'namespace:grDevices'

Tags: r, failed-installation

I've been trying for several hours to install the AICcmodavg package in R, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Error: object ‘palette.colors’ is not exported by 'namespace:grDevices'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘unmarked’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/unmarked’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp7feWfN/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("unmarked") :
  installation of package ‘unmarked’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've tried installing on R and R-Studio on Windows, including several different versions of R, and R on Ubuntu. I tried installing all the dependencies individually, and I think I narrowed down the issue to the package 'unmarked,' which gives the same error as when trying to install AICcmodavg. Installing with `install.packages('unmarked')` as well as downloading from source gives the same error.

How can I fix or avoid this error about 'palette.colors' so I can successfully use AICcmodavg? I'm not doing anything involving colors, but grDevices does load with `library(grDevices)`.

Using R 3.6.3 on Ubuntu, but also tried other newer and older versions on Ubuntu/Windows with same result.

Comment: `palette.colors` was added in R 4.0.0.  Not sure where the requirement is coming from (I don't see it anywhere in the code base of `unmarked` or `AICcmodavg`), but I would definitely try updating to the most recent R (4.2.1) unless you have a really good reason to use an older version -- it will greatly reduce these kinds of headaches.

Comment: R(4.2.1) ?grDevices::palette.colors  palettecolors((n = NULL, palette = "Okabe-Ito", alpha, recycle = FALSE) -  upgrade as suggested.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Interestingly Unmarked says R 2.12 works, and AICcmodavg says 3.2. Thanks for helping me sort this out.